# How to debug Stackoverflow Exception on a Win8 background task

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, stack-overflow, background-agents

I have a Windows Store 8.1 App where the background task throws a Stackoverflow Exception before it completes. The task uses Reactive Extensions and a third party library.

I have tried debugging through the agent, but I cannot find the location where the exception is thrown.

Are there any good ways to debug this problem?

Comment: What debugger are you using? Visual Studio? And if so, what version?

Answer (score 0):

If the stack overflow is caused by recursion and your debugger supports this feature, you can sprinkle some breakpoints around your code and tell them not to break until their hit count greater than some big number:

[image]